# A negative person

Tags: idioms, epithet-requests

What is the best word that I could use to describe a person that seems to attract negative situations? Every time I am around him/her, something bad always seems to happen. Is there a word to describe this person?

Comment: No problem. What is your first?

Comment: You have a few answers to get you started but we're trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call such a person a *[jinx](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jinx)*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Lightning rod](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightning_rod)*, figuratively a "person or thing that is a target for negative reactions and distracts criticism from another target" is an alternative to *[jinx](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jinx)*, a "person or thing supposed to bring bad luck", as is *[jonah](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jonah)*, a "person or object which is deemed to cause bad luck; a jinx".

Answer (score 1):

All of these are used in context alongside the idea of "luck" or that this person is simply a victim that attracts negative situations.  If you're trying to describe the person as having a negative disposition (and possibly causing his/her own suffering) then you may use these idioms.  However, idioms are strictly informal, use caution in professional settings.

Negative people can be called

- Debbie Downer
- Susie Raincloud
- Negative Nancy
- Grumpy Gus

These refer to disposition rather than situational negativity...I don't know if this helps.